# Twitter and facebook integration in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, twitter, cocos2d-iphone

I'm wanting to integrate Twitter and Facebook into a game using Cocos2D. I just want simple stuff like tweeting "I scored xxx", posting similar message to Facebook page, etc. I've seen numerous libraries offering to make my life easier - ShareKit, AddThis, etc - but I've also read things from people saying they are not that easy, not supported, and so on.

I could just go and get the facebook and twitter SDKs and integrate them in, but I was wondering if anyone had any recommendation for something that I've missed. I need to support iOS4 and 5 so I the library should use the built-in twitter features in iOS5 if present I guess.

Any suggestions or comments on this - perhaps I've just missed something really obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For Facebook,Ofcourse you can use facebook SDK and configure it https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk . But You may get lots of questions in that. Better read documentation given in facebook website and do it. Feel free to ask any doubt in that.

2)For Twitter, you can use twitter framework which is inbuilt in ios5. Its pretty easy. Try to use tweet sheet in that. It will give a good experience and consistency to the users of ios5.
 But You also have to integrate MGTwitterEngine( https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine ) to give support for ios4 and and its prior versions. Its little difficult.

Hope You got it.

Comment: This is what I'd found out already - I was wondering there was a library that would do all of this together. I've been looking at ShareKit (ShareKit 2.0) and that seems to integrate twitter and Facebook and can handle iOS5's twitter integration. Had any experience of that?

Comment: Ya Lot's of experience on that. But i wont encourage you to use that. Because It's already outdated. If you integrate that API into your app, then it will show 31 warnings. And if you release your app , then your "share" codings may not work in the first day itself. Anyway if you want, go ahead.

Comment: Is ShareKit 2.0 (not getShareKit.com) out of date? I don't mind writing my own (like you suggest), but if there's a library already out there and proven, it will save me time! Thanks.

Comment: That is an official site for Sharekit. https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit . I know it will save you lot of time. So use that API for just 15 mins. You will definitely finish that very fast and if you like that, then great and leave my answer. If you think that is not good, then start to work on it. All the best yar.

Answer (score 4):

You can share on Facebook by simply inserting the following line of codes.
For twitter I think there isn't exists such an easy way.

```
NSString *urlString = @"any url";
NSString *title = @"My score is 999";
NSString *shareUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@&t=%@", urlString , title];
shareUrlString = [shareUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:shareUrlString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
[url release];
```

Comment: wow, fanstastic. This is what I was looking for. Do you know any other magic commands like this that can post to flickr or twitter? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't working anymore. Facebook is rejecting to post message on users wall.

Answer (score 4):

You can  share on twitter using following code

```
  twt = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [twt setInitialText:@"Scorred 1000"];
    [twt addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
    twt.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) { 
        switch (result) {
            case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled: 
                 [twt dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

                   break;

            case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:

                //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];                     
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        [twt dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some tutorials for a facebook and a twitter helper Class I hope it helps... http://ludosimagos.tumblr.com/